# Will an XML sitemap make affect my website's PCI compliance?

Tags: seo, e-commerce, sitemap, pci-dss

I have an ecommerce website that's PCI compliant, and the website does not have an XML sitemap. The previous webmaster stated that he removed the sitemap because it caused the website to fail PCI validation testing. (We use the McAfee SECURE service for automated testing.)  I'd like to restore the sitemap for SEO, but I don't want to jeopardize our compliance.

Assuming that my new sitemap only includes relevant product/information link information, do I have anything to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t-nez,
I work for a merchant service provider, www.banckardclub.com, as the lead SEO. The XML sitemap will not cause your site to fail PCI compliance. We have an XML sitemap and we submit to google, and other search engines. We pass our compliance test with out a problem.

Have your webmaster look into the problem some more.

Answer (score 0):

Create an account on Webmaster tools and if you encounter problems search the help, this should not be a problem.